# Keep aspect ratio in JSSOR Thumbnailnavigator

Tags: javascript, jssor

is it possible to keep the `aspect ratio` within the `thumbnailnavigator`?

I've tried the option `$FillMode`  for `$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions` but that changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of thumbnail is specified by css (css of thumbnail navigator skin).
There is nothing done to resize thumbnail in jssor javascript code.

The thumbnail can be in html content format, if you use the following code to define thumbnail, you have  chance to customize image size.

```
<div u="thumb">
    <!-- Any content is allowed. You can customize size for the following image as well. -->
    <img u="thumb" src="url" />
</div>
```